# Rendering of HTML headings and lists

Tags: html, xhtml, rendering

I have XHTML code that looks like this:

```
<h2><ul>
 <li>thing one</li>
 <li>thing two</li>
 <li>thing three</li>
</ul></h2>
```

It doesn't validate, but it does work fine on all browsers I've tested. It renders like this:

### - thing one
- thing two
- thing three

If I change it to this (which is valid), then it doesn't render the same way:

```
<ul>
 <li><h2>thing one</h2></li>
 <li><h2>thing two</h2></li>
 <li><h2>thing three</h2></li>
</ul>
```

It renders like this:

- ### thing one
- ### thing two
- ### thing three

How can I write valid XHTML that will produce the same rendering as the first snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what the `<h2>` element is for. If you want to style an unordered list, give it a class:

```
<ul class="big">
   <li>thing one</li>
   <li>thing two</li>
   <li>thing three</li>
</ul>
```

And then add some CSS:

```
.big {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: block;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jQ8Qj/**

Comment: Yes, but suppose I want to exactly mimic the style of <h2>, but don't know what that style is?

Comment: @nerdfever.com: You can't do that with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

They don't like when you nest block level elments with inline elements. Use a class to style the list items.

```
<ul class="myclass">
 <li>thing one</li>
 <li>thing two</li>
 <li>thing three</li>
</ul>
```